# "Скажи, что с тобой": члены предложения

Tags: синтаксис

Как разобрать предложение по членам?
*Скажи* — сказуемое; *что с тобой* — сказуемое?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> “Скажи, что с тобой”
>
> Как разобрать предложение по членам? *Скажи* — сказуемое; *что с
>   тобой* — сказуемое?

***Скажи*** — сказуемое, или (по другой терминологии) главный член односоставного предложения.

***Что*** — подлежащее; сказуемого во втором предложении нет (предложение эллиптическое); ***с тобой*** — дополнение.